# Labview - How to select data from MS access table as input array?

Tags: ms-access, labview

I'm trying to make an array from a set of selectable cells in MS access.

Here's a section of my access DB:

[image]

I want the user to be able to select the cells with these numbers, dynamically (while code is running) and an array is created by selecting different cells. How can this be done in labview?

Thanks,

Comment: Access has fields, not cells. So what do you mean by 'selectable cells'?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the correct code to work with the database (NI's DB toolkit, LabSQL, call the ADO.NET code directly, etc.) and get the data you want from the DB.
2. Place a listbox or multicolumn listbox on the front panel, change its selection mode to have 0 or more elements, so its data type becomes an array.
3. Use the Item Names property for the listbox to feed the data from the DB into the listbox.
4. The user will now need to select multiple items. This can be done by holding Ctrl, or you can call a Windows API function to press and release Ctrl on mouse enter/leave events, or you can use the Mouse Down event to figure out which row the user clicked on and use that to modify the value of the listbox (which is an array of the indices of the selected rows).
5. Once the user is done, you can read the value of the listbox (from its terminal) to get the indices, and use that to index the data from the Item Names property or from the original data you got from the DB.